What steps can I take to get my SearchandFilterBar working in this code and what could the problem be?
I want the SearchandFilterBar to toggle the ShowDestinationSeachView filter, however when I click on the search button nothing happens.
I have tried to remove the SearchandFilterBar from the toolbar too see whether the functionality was flawed because it was in the toolbar however that did not do anything, just changed the appearance.
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showMenu = false
    @State private var showDestinationSearchView = false
    @StateObject var exploreViewModel = ExploreViewModel(service: ExploreService())

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State private var location: String = "" // Example location binding

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Group {
                    // No user logged in
                    if viewModel.userSession == nil {
                                        LoginView()
                                    } else {
                                        if showDestinationSearchView {
                                            DestinationSearchView(show: $showDestinationSearchView, viewModel: exploreViewModel)
                                        } else {
                                            mainInterfaceView
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                
                if showMenu {
                    ZStack {
                        Color(.black)
                            .opacity(showMenu ? 0.25 : 0.0)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            showMenu = false
                        }
                    }
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                    SideMenuView()
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .offset(x: showMenu ? 0 : -300, y: 100)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
            }
            // .navigationTitle("Home") // Removed to hide default title
            // .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        if let user = viewModel.currentUser {
                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation {
                                    showMenu.toggle()
                                }
                            }) {
                                KFImage(URL(string: user.profileImageUrl))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Custom Search and Filter Bar
                        SearchAndFilterBar(location: $exploreViewModel.searchLocation)
                            .frame(width: 200) // Adjust width as needed
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                                    showDestinationSearchView.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                showMenu = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    var mainInterfaceView: some View {
        MainTabView()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
    }
}



Note, NavigationView is deprecated you should use NavigationStack.
I suspect MainTabView() in your mainInterfaceView contains a TabView, and TabView should not be inside NavigationStack.
